# ES6 destructuring/cloning a subset of an object

Tags: ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm still getting used to destructuring in ES2015/ES6 and wondered if there's a nice way to clone certain keys of an object using it. It's a little hard to explain in words so I'll let the code do the talking. Here's a simplified version of what I have at the moment:

```
const objectWithLoadsOfData = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd'
};

const objectWithDataSubset = {
  a: objectWithLoadsOfData.a,
  b: objectWithLoadsOfData.b
}
```

It works, but it seems like it could be simplified with destructuring somehow. Potentially something like:

```
const objectWithDataSubset = objectWithLotsOfData {a, b};
```

Obviously this is invalid, but is there something like this that exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a functionality that works exactly the way you describe it.

However, with ES6 you can use [a shorter notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions) where the name of the key equals the name of the variable that holds the value, i.e. `{a: a, b: b}` is equivalent to `{a, b}`.

```
const {a, b} = objectWithLotsOfData;
const objectWithDataSubset = {a, b}
```

Comment: I never thought about using left hand assignments, that's not a bad workaround. It gets pretty hefty once you start using proper data but this is probably the right answer.